# docker python api: how do I know when instance is ready?

Tags: python, docker

I have a python module that starts a brand new docker postgres container like so:

```
import docker, time

client = docker.from_env()

containers = client.containers.list(all=True) # all checks for dead ones

container = client.containers.run(
    image="postgres",
    detach=True,
    ports={5432: 5555},
    name="postgres_test",
    user="postgres",
    environment={"POSTGRES_PASSWORD": "foo", "POSTGRES_DB": "test_db"}
)
time.sleep(10)
```

The code above works. One thing that I'm not particularly fond of is the last statement - `time.sleep(10)`. Instead of sleeping, I would rather the `docker.containers.run()` blocks or I query the container to find out when it has initialised.

How can I remove the `time.sleep(10)` line and have blocking functionality ?

Comment: If your container runs a service, poke the service to see if it's operational.

Comment: That whole `container.attrs["State"]` looks bogus to me - it's just a bunch of zeros.

Comment: Docker does not know and does not care if a service in a container is ready by its own definition. It just knows if the main process it started is running or not. So there is no way to get the information if PostgresQL has finished initializing from docker.

Comment: Just as an addition: kubernetes with its readiness probes has such a feature.

Comment: Of possible interest: [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize) specifically: [Waiting for other dependencies](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize#waiting-for-other-dependencies)